# executemany() Get Stuck on Oracle Load

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I have this script to load data into an Oracle table in batches. Till yesterday it was working fine, however all of a sudden it has started not executing as expected. Now, executemany() would halt indefinitely and won't load any data to oracle table. I have to kill terminal session to stop the execution, otherwise it won't stop and keep on running.

```
   sql='insert into TABLE_1 values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12)'
   df_list = dataset.values.tolist() # dataset contains ~7000 records

   batch_size = 100 # batch was set to 5,000 originally, for testing purpose reduced to 100
   data_len = len(df_list)
   iterations = data_len // batch_size if data_len % batch_size == 0 else (data_len // batch_size) + 1

   for i in np.arange(0, iterations):
      start = i * batch_size
      end = min((start + batch_size) , data_len)
      print(f'Exporting records from {start} to {end}.')
      subset = df_list[start:end]

      cursor.executemany(sql, subset) # progress halts here and doesn't move forward

   con.commit()
```

Prior to this insert query, I am executing a Select statement using same cursor and connection object and it works fine.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check for an open transaction (another user has inserted/updated/deleted rows in the table you are trying to manipulate and hasn't committed or rolled back their transaction yet).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Anthony Tuininga. Interestingly we found that our oracle space is almost consumed, and it is causing issues while loading data to oracle tables.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out!